# nHibernate queryover complex query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I've been battling this all day and can't seem to get the result I want. I want to get all the nodes that has a certain tag in their tag collection.

I'm using this QueryOver command but I'm getting all the possible nodes even though it looks to me as it should only be one.

```
    public IEnumerable<Node> GetAllWithTag(int tagId)
    {
        tags = new List<Tag>();
        Node node = null;
        Tag tagQ = null;

        var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Tag>(() => tagQ)
            .Where(tag1 => tag1.Id == tagId).DetachedCriteria;

        subQuery = subQuery.SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id"));

        var nodes = _applicationUnitOfWork.GetSession().QueryOver<Node>(
            () => node).Where(Subqueries.Exists(subQuery)).List<Node>();

        return nodes;
    }
```

I am using this strange setup because I got a method error when I tried to use Contains on node.Tags. So I read around a bit and it seems most everyone goes with a solution like this. I just can't figure out where I'm doing something stupid. Most thankful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`JoinQueryOver` or `JoinAlias`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations)?

Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetAllWithTag(int tagId)
{
    return _applicationUnitOfWork.GetSession().QueryOver<Node>()
        .JoinQueryOver<Tag>(n => n.Tags)
            .Where(t => t.Id == tagId)
            .List<Node>();
}
```